# PowerShell Get-PnPListItem Not returning all the Fields

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I am new to using PowerShell with regards to pulling data from SharePoint using `Get-PnPListItem`.

It gets the rows I need, the problem is that it returns only the `ID, Title, and GUID` columns.

I need all the columns in my value display. Any advise?

```
Write-Host "Please enter URL of the SharePoint site:"
$url = Read-Host

Write-Host "Please enter List Name of the SharePoint site:"
$ListName = Read-Host 

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $url -UseWebLogin
Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName
```

Comment: Rather than using `Write-Host` you can use `Read-Host` to both prompt and get input eg: `$url = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter URL of the SharePoint site"`

Answer (score 0):

The `get-pnplistitem` cmdlet has a -Fields parameter, where you can specify the included columns. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnplistitem?view=sharepoint-ps) of the cmdlet...

Comment: Yes I already tried this, but the thing is this should be a reusable script so it should get all the Fields even if I use this in different SP List

Comment: Docs suggest all fields are returned by default? "The fields to retrieve. If not specified all fields will be loaded in the returned list object."

Comment: Yup, that is why it is weird that it only gives 3 field value. Based form the document if we do not right the -Field it should return all of the value on the SP List

Answer (score 0):

All fields are returned by default, as you said. However, to display all the field values you need to use the property **FieldValues**. Hence, the full code should be as follows...

`(Get-PnPListItem -List "List Title" -Id 31).FieldValues`